# Ejabberd: How to get list of muc_rooms / disco_items via API for which user is affiliated to?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am working on setting up API for ejabebrd muc_rooms.

Now one user is affiliated with 10 teams.

Is there any API or and way from API to fetch the list of teams ( muc_rooms ) of the user?

I tried `get_user_rooms` but realized that the list comes after joining team only.

In mobile SDK disco_items available , but to do the same on web I need API solution for the same

Answer (score 0):

There is no API command to obtain a list of rooms for which a user has some affiliation. The list of affiliations is not stored in the databases in a way easy to search for it.